# Using do loops with certain conditions

Tags: c

So I am making a Craps game in my C class and am having trouble with a particular point. *If a user rolls a 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 or 10 that is considered a point. If the user rolls a 7 after rolling a point they lose*. My problem is if a user rolls a point, and then they roll again and the sum is equal to their point they win. My program works if they roll a 7 after their point, but not if they roll sum of their point again. 
Sorry I know the question is confusing.

```
        case 1: printf("Enter your name here: ");
            scanf("%s", name);

            for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(strcmp(name, pl[j].players)==0){
                    set = 1;

                    printf("* * * * * * * * * *\n");
                    printf("Press ENTER to roll the dice");
                    getchar();
                    getchar();

                    dice = (rand()%(6-1+1)+1);
                    dice1 = (rand()%(6-1+1)+1);
                    sum = dice + dice1;

                    printf("\nThe values of the dice are %d and %d whose sum is %d\n", dice, dice1, sum);

                    if(sum == 7 || sum == 11)
                    {
                        win++;
                        pl[j].wincount = win;
                        pl[j].balance = pl[j].balance + 10;
                        printf("\nYou win the game. \nYour balance is now: %d\n", pl[j].balance);
                        break;
                    }

                    else if((sum == 2) || (sum == 3) || (sum == 12))
                    {
                        lose++;
                        pl[j].balance = pl[j].balance-1;
                        printf("You lose :(\nYou balance is now: %d\n", pl[j].balance);

                        dice = (rand()%(6-1+1)+1);
                        dice1 = (rand()%(6-1+1)+1);
                        sum = dice + dice1;
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            printf("\nYou rolled a 'point' you must now roll again.\n");
                            printf("* * * * * * * * * *\n");
                            printf("Press ENTER to roll the dice again");
                            getchar();
                            getchar();

                            dice = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1) + 1);
                            dice1 = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1) + 1);
                            sum = dice + dice1;
                            printf("\nThe values of the dices are %d and %d whose sum is %d\n", dice, dice1, sum);

                        }while((sum != 7) && (sum != point));

                        if(sum == 7)
                        {
                            lose++;
                            pl[j].balance = pl[j].balance - 1;
                            printf("You lose :(\nYou balance is now: %d\n", pl[j].balance);
                        }


                        else if(sum == point)
                        {
                            win++;
                            pl[j].wincount = win;
                            pl[j].balance = pl[j].balance + 10;
                            printf("\nYou won the game, you rolled your point \nYour balance is now: %d\n", pl[j].balance);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not seeing `point` on the left side of an `=`

Comment: i fogot to say that i set point = sum; but i tried putting it in multiple places but could still not find the correct line to place it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to put it right before the `do` ?

Comment: i fixed it @phantom. in the do while i set dice + dice1 = point because if you dont roll a 2, 3, 7, 11 or 12 the sum of the dice become the players 'point'. thanks for the help, much appreciated